# I am trying to make rows that keep on going even after it starts a new one with Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I know the question is kind of vague, but it is really hard to explain over words. Here is a jsfiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/y1yyp3o0/ 
I am trying to get the boxes with words to underneath the columns. So, like I want the web column to go under neath the AP CS column. And then I want the sharing research column to go under the Computer Architecture column. I have a few more, but those are just what I have down now. How Would I get this to work?

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is empty

Comment: Oops, apparently I forgot to update it when I put everything on. Here is the new link. http://jsfiddle.net/a7kbt4dj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I am understanding you right, but I think it would be best if you separated the `tool-column` elements from the bootstrap columns like so:

```
<div class="tools row">
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <div class="tool-column">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7kbt4dj/2/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! How would I get them to touch like they were? I like the feel, and look of that a little better.

Comment: They were touching before because your code was incorrect. By default, Foundation adds padding between each column, you can just add a custom class to remove the padding from those columns if you want them to touch: http://jsfiddle.net/a7kbt4dj/3/

Comment: Well you learn something everyday, eh? That works great! Thank you very much, and I will remember to keep all of that in mind.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help!